# Is there a way to make Dart server websocket implementation compatible with Phantom 1.9.7 headless browser (another websocket standard that is)?

Tags: websocket, dart, phantomjs, rfc6455

According to the [WebSocketTransformer](https://api.dartlang.org/apidocs/channels/stable/dartdoc-viewer/dart:io.WebSocketTransformer) docs, it says it tries to upgrade [HttpRequests](https://api.dartlang.org/apidocs/channels/stable/dartdoc-viewer/dart-io.HttpRequest) according to the [RFC6455](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6455) web socket standard:

> This transformer strives to implement web sockets as specified by RFC6455.

And provides this Dart example code:

```dart
HttpServer server;
server.listen((request) {
  if (...) {
    WebSocketTransformer.upgrade(request).then((websocket) {
      ...
    });
  } else {
    // Do normal HTTP request processing.
  }
});
```

Now if you search through PhantomJS' issue tracker you can find issue:

[11018 Update to final websocket standard](https://github.com/ariya/phantomjs/issues/11018)

Which basically says that the latest PhantomJS (1.9.7) uses an old web socket standard (I still haven't figured out what version sends out the `Sec-WebSocket-Key1` information, but I assume its not the RFC6455 version).

So basically, my problem is that when I run PhantomJS headless browser towards my site that uses Dart 1.3.3, websocket server implementation (basically some upgrade code as I pasted above), it says:

Headers from PhantomJS:

> sec-websocket-key1: 327J w6iS/b!43 L2j5}2 2
> connection: Upgrade
> origin: http://mydomain.com
> upgrade: WebSocket
> sec-websocket-key2: 42   d 7 64 84622
> host: mydomain.com

Dart:

> WebSocketTransformer.isUpgradeRequest(request) = false
>
> WebSocketException: Invalid WebSocket upgrade request

The upgrade of the request failed (I assume it because of the mis match of versions).

**My question is, until Phantom JS gets updated with 2.0, is there a way I can fix my Dart back-end so it would handle PhantomJS websockets as well?**

According to the docs of [WebSocketTransformer](https://api.dartlang.org/apidocs/channels/stable/dartdoc-viewer/dart:io.WebSocketTransformer), the upgrade function has two arguments, one HttpRequest mandatory, and a second optional argument:

```dart
static Future<WebSocket> upgrade(HttpRequest request, {Function protocolSelector(List<String> protocols)})
```

Could this maybe help me some how?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The protocols won't help you. These allow to agree on a special protocol that is used after the handshake for communication. But you can't modify the handshake and the exchanged fields themselves.

What you could do is make a complete own websocket implementation (directly based on Dart HTTP and TCP) that matches the the old implementation that PhantomJS uses. But that won't work with newer clients. By that way you also might be able to make an implementation that supports several versions (by checking the headers when you receive the handshake HTTP request and depending on the handshake forward to another implementation.

You would have to do at least your own `WebSocketTransformer` implementation. For this you could start by copying Darts interface and implementation and modify it on all places you need (check Licenses). If the actual WebSocket behavior after the handshake is compatible in the two RFCs you could reuse Darts `WebSocket` class. If this is not the case (other framing, etc.) then you would also have to do your own `WebSocket` class.

Some pseudo code based on yours:

```
HttpServer server;
server.listen((request) {
  if (...) { // websocket condition
    if (request.headers.value("Sec-WebSocket-Key1") != null) {
      YourWebSocketTransformer.upgrade(request).then((websocket) {
        ... // websocket might need to be a different type than Dart's WebSocket
      });
    } 
    else {
      WebSocketTransformer.upgrade(request).then((websocket) {
        ...
      });
    }
  }
  else {
    // Do normal HTTP request processing.
  }
});
```

I don't know your application, but it's probably not worth the effort. Bringing the old websocket implementation into Dart is probably the same effort as bringing the official implementation to PhantomJS. Therefore I think fixing PhantomJS should be preferred.

Comment: I was really hoping for a switch I could flip in the code, so that other standards would work as well :) But maybe you are right, this is not worth the effort and its better to focus on better things while waiting for PhantomJS 2.0. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

"No."

[`HttpRequest.headers` is immutable](https://api.dartlang.org/apidocs/channels/stable/dartdoc-viewer/dart-io.HttpRequest#id_headers), so you can't massage the request headers into a format that Dart is willing to accept. You can't do any Ruby-style monkey-patching, because Dart does not allow dynamic evaluation.

You *can*, should you choose a path of insanity, implement a compatible version of WebSockets by handling the raw `HttpRequest` yourself when you see a request coming in with the expected headers. I believe you can re-implement the [`WebSocket`](https://api.dartlang.org/apidocs/channels/stable/dartdoc-viewer/dart-io.WebSocket) class if necessary. The [source for the `WebSocket` is here](https://chromium.googlesource.com/external/dart/+/refs/heads/master/dart/sdk/lib/io/websocket.dart).

Comment: So, it sounds like, according to you, you cannot specify which web socket standard Dart back-end should use?

Comment: I went digging through Dart's source code and unfortunately could find no such option. Like the Dart developers always say, though, "Open a bug report at dartbug.com/new"

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it's possible to do that through inheritance. It's impossible in dart to avoid overriding.
If you have the time and you really need this, you can re-implement some method to patch the websocket for PhatomJS

```
class MyWebSocket extends WebSocket {
    MyWebSocket(/* ... */) : super(/* ... */);

    methodYouNeedToOverride(/* ... */) {
        super.methodYouNeedToOverride(/* ... */)
        // Your patch
    }
}
```

This way will allow you to access to "protected" variable or method, may be useful for a patching

But be careful, [WebSocket](https://chromium.googlesource.com/external/dart/+/refs/heads/master/dart/sdk/lib/io/websocket.dart) are just the visible part, all the implementation is in [websocket_impl.dart](https://chromium.googlesource.com/external/dart/+/refs/heads/master/dart/sdk/lib/io/websocket_impl.dart)

Comment: Heya. Thanks for your response. However, I am looking for an API-wise solution, to be able to change the websocket standard to be used.